# How to get an Int result from array in PHP /MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have written code with the intention of getting an integer quantity but the result am getting is in an array format.How do I convert that from an array to an integer. Am getting the results from a MySQL database...
Here is my code, Instead of it returning an array I need to get the array value that is at that key

```
function hcQuantiy($db, $isbn)
 {
     $query = "SELECT num_hardcover from inventory where isbn = :isbn";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->closeCursor();
return $result;
   }
```

Comment: Do you want the num_hardcover has the result?

Answer (score 2):

If you need only one row dont use the method fetch**All** which returns an array of rows, use only fetch, which returms an array with one row.

Use PDO::FETCH_NUM for fetch and get the index 0 of the result. 
Than convert the result to an int. And there you have your quantity :)

Your code edited:

```
   function hcQuantiy($db, $isbn) {
        $query = "SELECT num_hardcover FROM inventory WHERE isbn = :isbn";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);
        $statement->execute(); 
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
        $statement->closeCursor(); 
        return intval($result[0]); 
   }
```

Comment: works like a charm...only thing is I didn't see it until I had spent an hour going in loops thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do accessing the array  eg:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo $row["num_hardcover"] . '<br />;
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-   . thanks  ..  .. i have just edit  .. hope is the right solution

Comment: let's see what the OP has to say. PDO isn't my strongest when it comes to converting an array to int.

Comment: You got to love those "moments of silence" eh? Well, we'll see who gets the "green" in about 4 mins. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-   .. i have  a lot of green  flag .. in a day..  but this time could be that the green  is for others .. ..  but  i . don't like much the wait .. .

Comment: Yeah, it's the "waiting" and not knowing if answers given are what they're looking for, leaving people wondering if what they posted works for them or not, in turn taking the word "guesswork" to a higher/new level.